# Sorting array doesn't work properly when some items have unknown values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Say I have array of objects

```
[
  {
      "name": "John", 
      "height": "172", 
      "weight": "87"
  }, 
  {
      "name": "Tom", 
      "height": "167", 
      "weight": "67"

  }, 
  {
      "name": "James", 
      "height": "156", 
      "weight": "uknown"
  }, 
  {
      "name": "Jeremy", 
      "height": "unknown", 
      "weight": "85"
  }, 
]
```

Now if I want to sort them by height I can do `persons.sort((a, b) => b.height - a.height);` likewise if I want to sort them by weight I can do the same but with weight `persons.sort((a, b) => b.weight - a.weight);`

So far this would work fine, however some of the values are unknown, and if I'm holding this array in some state and sort them by either the unknown values mess it up and it doesn't sort properly. In a case where there are alot more objects that 4, it sorts to some point but as soon as it hits an object with an unknown property it messes it up and the rest of the array is then not sorted properly. How can I overcome this? Perhaps doing something pushing the items with unknown value at the bottom?

Comment: If possible you can use `null` instead of `unknown` & to sort `persons.sort((a,b)=>(a?.height - b?.height)`.

Comment: persons.sort((a, b) => (b.height || -Infinity) - (a.height || -Infinity) );

Comment: This doesn't quite work in my case, I'm receiving the objects from an API and cannot change those values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is handle the specific cases when height/weight is `unknown` and return the appropriate value

For example:

```js
const items = [
  {
      "name": "John", 
      "height": "172", 
      "weight": "87"
  }, 
  {
      "name": "Tom", 
      "height": "167", 
      "weight": "67"

  }, 
  {
      "name": "James", 
      "height": "156", 
      "weight": "uknown"
  }, 
  {
      "name": "Jeremy", 
      "height": "unknown", 
      "weight": "85"
  }, 
    {
      "name": "Jeremy2", 
      "height": "162", 
      "weight": "85"
  }, 
    {
      "name": "Jeremy3", 
      "height": "unknown", 
      "weight": "85"
  }, 
];

items.sort((a,b) => {
  if(b.height === 'unknown' && a.height ==='unknown') return 0;
  else if(b.height === 'unknown') return -1;
  else if(a.height === 'unknown') return 1;
  else return a.height - b.height;
});

console.log(items);
```

The comparator function **compare(a, b)** works like this:

```
if return value sort > 0, sort b before a.
else if return value sort < 0, sort a before b.
else if return value === 0  keep original order of a and b.
```

[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description)

**Edit:**

If one is dealing with comma seperated strings, one convert to number first:

```
items.sort((a,b) => {
  if(b.height === 'unknown' && a.height ==='unknown') return 0;
  else if(b.height === 'unknown') return -1;
  else if(a.height === 'unknown') return 1;
  else return parseFloat(a.height.replace(/,/g, '')) -
parseFloat(b.height.replace(/,/g, ''))
});
```

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#description)

Comment: This worked well for me, thank you :) could you by any chance explain how exactly this works, what do the 0, 1 and -1 values represent?

Comment: Have edited the answer. Do read up the documentation i have attached

Comment: Additionally, I found that one of the values also has a comma, 1,487 for example and instead of seeing it as 1487 it's not understanding it properly and it messes up the rest of the sort

Comment: The ideal way for you would be to convert these strings to numbers and then do the computation.

Comment: @KivDaor have edited